# How to left join in query builder without entity in doctrine zend

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, left-join, zend-framework3

Hi I have M:M relationship between two tables, Contacts and Tags and their M:M table is called Contacts_Tags:

```
Contacts
------------
ID
Name

Tags
-----------
ID
Name

Contacts_Tags
--------------
Contact_ID
Tag_ID
```

I have entities for Contacts called `Contact` and for Tags called `Tag` but not for Contacts_Tags table.

I want to left join in query builder

```
$queryBuilder                    =  $this->entityManager->getRepository(Contact::class)->createQueryBuilder("o")->select("o");
$queryBuilder->leftJoin(//here, "et", "WITH", "et.Contact_ID = o.ID")
             ->leftJoin(Tag::class, "t", "WITH", "t.ID = et.Tag_ID")
;
```

But I cannot figure out how to add it. I tried documentations but it says to add Entity when I add entity of `ContactTag` it throws error that entity should have primary key.

Any idea?

Comment: If this is a M:M **bi-directional** relationship, why not simply: `$contact->getTags()` or `$tag->getContacts()` ? If it's uni-directional with `Contact` as the owning side, you can do `$contact->getTags()` and if `Tag` is the owner, then `$tag->getContacts()`. If you really want/need to use the QB for this, then you might want to read the class code. Also, I'm thinking you should use `Join::ON` instead of `"WITH"` (see `\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder#leftJoin`)

Answer (score 0):

To do left join :

```
$queryBuilder->join(table, condition, columns, $queryBuilder::JOIN_LEFT);
with :
table is the name of a table or another Select or array [alias => table]
condition is a string (the same as in Sql language)
columns is an array like [alias => column_name, ...] or [column_name, ...], may be empty
$queryBuilder is a Select, can be replaced by \Zend\Sql\Select::JOIN_LEFT
```